# two json encoded array to split into 2 different arrays

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

In my test.php which is called by an ajax

I have this

```
echo json_encode($month);
echo json_encode($sum);
```

and then the result is

[image]

Then in my js file (part of my ajax)

```
success: function (dataofconfirm) {
    var $data = dataofconfirm;
    alert($data);
   }
```

The above result is caused by my alert, right? so moving on how can i split them by their group let's say like the one below

```
var $months = (The Jun to November);
var sums    = (the 3288 something and so on);
```

I tried splice but failed.

Thanks.

Comment: what is it you want $months and sums to **actually** contain (not this psuedo stuff in your question)

Comment: You should only send 1 json string back from your php script so that you can easily parse and use it in javascript.

Comment: So what's next. How can I seperate them from one another.
I did this `echo json_encode(array_merge(json_decode($a, true),json_decode($b, true)));`
RESULT:["May","Jun","July","123","234","444"]
How can i place may jun and july in a variable and 123,234,444 in another variable?

Comment: It's not clear what you need. If the sums are related to the months it doesn't make sense to split the data, you could instead combine the two arrays with `json_encode(array_combine($months,$counts));` and then filter in Javascript

Comment: what do you get if you console.log(dataofconfirm) ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just return one json object, containing your months and values?

```
$data = Array();
$data[0] = array("month" => "Jun", "value" => 1234546);    
$data[1] = array("month" => "Jul", "value" => 987654);    
.
.
etc

echo json_encode($data);
```

Then on client side:

```
success: function (dataofconfirm) {
var data = dataofconfirm;

for(var x = 0; x < data.length; x++
{
   var month = data[x].month;
   var value = data[x].value;
}
```

This way you can use each month and value pare separately or combine it in a month and value array as needed.